# How to track on which email client the mail has been opened via google analytics?

Tags: email, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, mailchimp

I tried and searched a lot to track email client but i am getting to use other bananatag or mailchimp tool. I dont want to use other tools. i only want to track which email client is being used or on which email client the mail has been opened. 
I tried capturing via HTTP_USER_AGENT but did not get only got the browser information. Used   document.referrer too but it returned "" .

How do mailchimp , banantag and other campaign tools figure out the mail client?

Answer (score 2):

Every email client will send a `user agent string`, but Google Analytics is optimized for web browser hits.  The email tracking vendors have accumulated the user-agent signatures of the most common email clients and do the mapping for you.  (See for instance [Udger Email Client List](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list#Email%20client).)

The GA interface does not give you direct access to the user-agent strings of your hits, so you can't implement this mapping yourself.

One can hope that as more clients use the GA measurement protocol for email tracking the GA team will see the need to provide alternative mappings.  When you *know* your hits are coming from email clients, it makes very little sense to map to web browsers.

As an particularly insidious example, Google's own GMail product identifies itself with this user-agent string:

> mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 5.1; rv:11.0) gecko firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com googleimageproxy)

Which ends up making it look like your hits came from Firefox v. 11 running on Windows NT, according to the canonical GA mapping.  :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't track this information with Google Analytics. You'll have to survey your users and use statistical analysis to determine which e-mail client(S) they use.

Comment: Thanks @kevintechie but how mailchimp and bananatag are able to do this?

Comment: What does Google Analytics Measurement Protocol do then, if not this?

Comment: The protocol doesn't send e-mail application client information. This is what the OP asked for. The GAMP can only send information obtained from a browser or from your application. It can't send data from someone else's application.

Answer (score 0):

You can track offsite activities with [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/). So you can fool your email template to include a blank image that sends out a hit to Google Analytics on each open of the email.

`<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-Y&cid=*|UNIQID|*&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=*|UNIQID|*&cs=email&cm=email&cn=*|CAMPAIGN_UID|*&cm1=1" />`

(example from a Mailchimp newsletter template)

Then you can select as a dimension in your event reports the Browser/Browser version and have a look at them[image]

This is based on this [article](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2013/06/17/email-tracking-google-analytics/) from [Lunametrics](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog)

Comment: This doesn't give you e-mail client info. It only gives you web browser info.